# How to get camera frame to process using swiftUI?

Tags: ios, camera, swiftui

I'm trying to get frame like VideoCapture in opencv using swiftUI

here is my code which is not working

I expected that "Got a frame!" should print in console when each frame from camera is available

at least, I can see the preview on the screen

How can I solve it or is there an any other idea?

If you have some reference to do same thing, It would be helpful

```
// For camera streaming
struct DemoVideoStreaming: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PreviewHolder()
        }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
    }
}




struct PreviewHolder: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PreviewHolder>) -> PreviewView {
        PreviewView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PreviewView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PreviewHolder>) {
    }

    typealias UIViewType = PreviewView
}



class PreviewView: UIView, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    private var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        var allowedAccess = false
        let blocker = DispatchGroup()
        blocker.enter()
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { flag in
            allowedAccess = flag
            blocker.leave()
        }
        blocker.wait()

        if !allowedAccess {
            print("!!! NO ACCESS TO CAMERA")
            return
        }

        // setup session
        // Step 3. AVCaptureSession
        let session = AVCaptureSession()
        session.beginConfiguration()

        let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera,
                                                  for : .video, position: .front) //alternate AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)
        guard videoDevice != nil, let videoDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice!), session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput) else {
            print("!!! NO CAMERA DETECTED")
            return
        }
        session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)


        let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "sample buffer"))
        guard session.canAddOutput(videoOutput) else { return }
        session.addOutput(videoOutput)


        session.commitConfiguration()
        self.captureSession = session
    }

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.self
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
        return layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    }

    // wrapping dispatch
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()

        if nil != self.superview {
            self.videoPreviewLayer.session = self.captureSession
            self.videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
            self.captureSession?.startRunning()
        } else {
            self.captureSession?.stopRunning()

        }
    }

    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        print("Got a frame!")
    }
}
```

Comment: How to make it full screen?

Answer (score 1):

that is because you didn't  sign  the  AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate  delegate to your code

here is how should it look like

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

final class PreviewView: UIView ,AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate{
private var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
var imageBufferHandler: ImageBufferHandler?
private var videoConnection: AVCaptureConnection!

init() {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
        
    var allowedAccess = false
    let blocker = DispatchGroup()
    blocker.enter()
    AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { flag in
        allowedAccess = flag
        blocker.leave()
    }
    blocker.wait()

    if !allowedAccess {
        print("!!! NO ACCESS TO CAMERA")
        return
    }

    // setup session
    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    session.beginConfiguration()

    let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera,
        for: .video, position: .unspecified) //alternate AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)
    guard videoDevice != nil, let videoDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice!), session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput) else {
        print("!!! NO CAMERA DETECTED")
        return
    }
    session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
    session.commitConfiguration()
    self.captureSession = session
    
    // setup video output
    let videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    videoDataOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)] as [String : Any]
    
    videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.queue.videosamplequeue")
    videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
    guard captureSession!.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput) else {
        fatalError()
    }
    captureSession!.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
    
    videoConnection = videoDataOutput.connection(with: .video)

}

override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.self
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
    return layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
}

override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    super.didMoveToSuperview()

    if nil != self.superview {
        self.videoPreviewLayer.session = self.captureSession
        self.videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resize
        self.captureSession?.startRunning()
        
    }
    else {
        self.captureSession?.stopRunning()
    }
}

func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    print("Got a frame!")

    if connection.videoOrientation != .portrait {
        connection.videoOrientation = .portrait
        return
    }
    
    if let imageBufferHandler = imageBufferHandler
    {
        imageBufferHandler(sampleBuffer)
    }
}}
```

don't forget to add the image buffer handler

```
typealias ImageBufferHandler = ((_ imageBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) -> ())
```